# Why does Tensorflow Classification Algorithm make same prediction all the time

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory("C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2/bin")

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import models
from keras import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

import os
print(len(os.listdir('COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/COVID/images')))
print(len(os.listdir('COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/Normal/images')))

import cv2
img = cv2.imread('COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/Normal/images/Normal-10005.png')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.imshow(img)
#plt.show()
print(img.shape)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/COVID.metadata.xlsx')
print(df.head())

urls = os.listdir('COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/COVID/images')
path = "COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/COVID/images/" + urls[0]
print(path)

def loadImages(path, urls, target):
  images = []
  labels = []
  for i in range(len(urls)):
    img_path = path + "/" + urls[i]
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = img / 255.0
    img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    images.append(img)
    labels.append(target)
  images = np.asarray(images)
  return images, labels

covid_path = "COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/COVID/images"
covidUrl = os.listdir(covid_path)
covidImages, covidTargets = loadImages(covid_path, covidUrl, 1)

print(len(covidUrl))
print(len(covidImages))

normal_path = "COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/Normal/images"
normal_urls = os.listdir(normal_path)
normalImages, normalTargets = loadImages(normal_path, normal_urls, 0)

viral_path = "COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset/Viral Pneumonia/images"
viral_urls = os.listdir(viral_path)
viralImages, viralTargets = loadImages(viral_path, viral_urls, 0)

print(covidImages.shape)
print(normalImages.shape)
print(viralImages.shape)

data = np.r_[covidImages, normalImages, viralImages]
print(data.shape)

targets = np.r_[covidTargets, normalTargets, viralTargets]
print(targets.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, targets, test_size=0.25)

#import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow import keras
#from keras import models
#from keras import Sequential
#from keras import layers
#from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
##

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, 3, input_shape=(100,100,3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=32,epochs=15,validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

plt.plot(model.history.history['accuracy'], label = 'train accuracy')
plt.plot(model.history.history['val_accuracy'],label = 'test_accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(model.history.history['loss'], label = 'train loss')
plt.plot(model.history.history['val_loss'],label = 'test_loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

url = "https://radiologyassistant.nl/assets/_1-old-1.jpg"
testimage = tf.keras.utils.get_file('X-ray', origin=url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
    testimage, target_size=(100, 100)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(predictions)
print(score)
```

Its supposed to classify it as COVID, normal, or Viral, however it the prediction always returns 1... I want it to return one of the three classes, I am not quite sure why it keeps returning 1 when printing predictions, please help. I am using a data set of COVID related pneumonia chest X-rays, Normal Chest x-rays and viral pneumonia chest xrays.

Answer (score 0):

it is for medical instruments BinaryCrossEntrophy classification because it required the most accurate from 0 to 1. I skipped the model path and sample as there are no data examples but one answer repeating may occur for these reasons.

1. **Model training and learning rates**, the model needs to learn in appropriate manners and stop or re-train in order that why image classification uses a custom callback class when testing ( for actually not use the custom callback class that is because data wide ranges and variety of data must be learning, the early stop may work well with scopes data but not always for new data )
2. **Folding and variety**, I used to train numbers recognitions from Thailand's public automatic telephony box exchange which is a large dataset. Create datasets as folds working with sample data and new data you will see the results as a long-time learning dense layer is made senses but longer-time convolution layers are critical parameters, those input voices are different by personality and domestic cultures.
3. **Feature extractions and enchantment methods**, sometimes input images are huge, and repeats of data, mathematics functions and wave properties work well with natural logarithms ( not only waves, bones, body and response are )
4. **Mapping and cross functions**, image masking, feature mapping by related data than feature extraction such as options selection, dictionary, and command and language model but for image classification image masking and info data ( geographic data, sexual, age and related )
5. **Model transform and database learning**, you will find sometimes for convenience use after training the model we transform knowledge into a simple dense layers model that we can remove or add layers and parameters for better results.

**The code is already correct experiments is the tasks.**

Sample: ( My template ) << There are many tasks to create a pair of sandals than you know to wear and feel comfortable to see grandmother >>

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # if( logs['loss'] <= 0.2 ):
            # self.model.stop_training = True
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.60 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```